# How to increase the number of available connections for a ChromiumWebBrowser?

Tags: chromium-embedded

I have a web screen with ChromiumWebBrowser which uses some GRPC services that return ResponseStream result, which means that connection is continuously open.
My understanding is that there are only a maximum number of 6 simultaneously active socket connections available, but I need at least one more.
Others having similar problems: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/522
My question is: Is there a way to increase the number of maximum connections in CefSettings/ChromiumWebBrowser?

I tried the following but didn't have any effect:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("max-connections", "20");
```

When I send a new grpc request it doesn't go through because I believe all sockets are used.

Comment: Are you trying to guess it? "max-connections" is not known command line parameter. 6 per host persistent connections are hardcoded in Chromium and can't be changed in runtime.